# Signing Data With Mechanism Python PyKCS11, LowLevel API

Tags: python, c++, encryption, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm trying to sign some data using CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS mechanism... I'm having trouble with the [lowlevel-API](http://pkcs11wrap.sourceforge.net/api/), as there is virtually no documentation and almost no examples. I'm attempting to do something almost identical to [Sign/verify PyKCS11 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827512/how-to-verify-signed-data-with-pykcs11-library) 
I can't seem to properly convert the code using the lowlevel(awful) API.

Here's some short snippets of my attempt.

```
a = CPKCS11Lib()
info = CK_INFO()
m = PyKCS11.LowLevel.CK_MECHANISM()
signature = ckbytelist()
m.mechanism = PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS
key = PyKCS11.LowLevel.CK_OBJECT_HANDLE()
slotInfo = CK_SLOT_INFO()
lib='/opt/PTK/lib/libcryptoki.so'
session = CK_SESSION_HANDLE()
sessionInfo = CK_SESSION_INFO()
tokenInfo = CK_TOKEN_INFO()
slotList = ckintlist()
objects = ckobjlist()

binaryData = "XYZ"
sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha256.update(str(bytearray(binaryData)))
digest = sha256.digest()
binaryData2 = '\x30\x31\x30\x0d\x06\x09\x60\x86\x48\x01\x65\x03\x04\x02\x01\x05\x00\x04\x20' + digest
signMechanism = PyKCS11.Mechanism(PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS, None)
signedData = str(a.C_Sign(CKA_PRIVATE, binaryData2, signMechanism))
print(signedData)
```

Getting this traceback for `signedData`

`def C_Sign(self, *args): return _LowLevel.CPKCS11Lib_C_Sign(self, *args)
TypeError: in method 'CPKCS11Lib_C_Sign', argument 2 of type 'CK_SESSION_HANDLE'`

Comment: Theoretically should I be able to use any pkcs11 interface?

Comment: Crypto notes: SHA1 != SHA256, it has a different output size. Not that it matters because SHA256_RSA_PKCS probably hashes the values itself, so you'd get a hash over the hash construction.

Comment: Is the different output size throwing the type error? @MaartenBodewes

Comment: Could you try giving it just the 32 byte  hash value?

Comment: ahh the `sha256 = hashlib.sha1()` was a typo when i was attempting to figure out the problem. I'll try passing just the hash value. Can't access the sever due to my location. Thanks for the tip, i'll see if it works. @MaartenBodewes

Comment: So, `signedData = session.CKA_Sign(CKA_PRIVATE, binaryData2, signMechanism)` is giving this traceback. Doesn't like attribute `CKA_Sign` ............. `signedData = session.CKA_Sign(CKA_PRIVATE, binaryData2, signMechanism)
  File "/home/tanner/pylib/PyKCS11/LowLevel.py", line 299, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, CK_SESSION_HANDLE, name)
  File "/home/tanner/pylib/PyKCS11/LowLevel.py", line 55, in _swig_getattr
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: C_Sign` @MaartenBodewes

Comment: There's an underlying problem in the init.py file or the LowLevel.py file that is only allowing me to use the lowlevel API. The problem is with the call to the C_Initialize function. I can't seem to debug the problem. Any clue where this occurs and how it can be fixed? @MaartenBodewes

Comment: Did you already limit `binaryData2` to just the digest value, so without the `\x30\x31` SHA-256 identifier?

Comment: Correct. It's giving me the same trackeback for C_Sign as i stated in the orignial post. @MaartenBodewes

Comment: Do I need a call to `C_SignInit` ? @MaartenBodewes

Comment: Probably not when directly calling sign, no. `SignInit`, `SignUpdate` and `SignFinal` (if I remember the names correctly) are the streaming versions of `Sign`.

Comment: `print("\tC_Login(): " + hex(a.C_Login(session, CKU_SO, pin)))
    print "C_OpenSession(): " + hex(a.C_OpenSession(slotList[0], PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION, session))
    print "C_Login(): " + hex(a.C_Login(session, PyKCS11.LowLevel.CKU_USER, pin))`      From here I call `C_FindObjects` and it prints attributes that are unique to the token @MaartenBodewes

Comment: Got that one wrong: "After calling C_SignInit, the application can either call C_Sign to sign in a single part; or call C_SignUpdate one or more times, followed by C_SignFinal, to sign data in multiple parts.". Makes sense right, you need to indicate the private key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119025/discussion-between-dj2-and-maarten-bodewes).